# What is the punishment for a Jewish woman who sleeps with a gentile (Non Jewish man)? Is the man and woman both punished?

Tags: gentiles, women

To my understanding the woman may receive lashes but what is the offense for the man? Sources please.

And are they punished?

Yes I am talking about an unmarried woman

Comment: Hi David and welcome to MY! If I'm correct, you are talking about an unmarried Jewish woman, right?

Comment: [Link](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960660/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Twelve.htm#v9).